# I cannot get my autoscaling group to reference my TargetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I am able to launch a simple autoscaling group. However, the problem comes when I try to set up an Application Load Balancer to direct traffic to my various instances. First, I created my load balancer, it was simple as well. The problem is creating the target group and the listener. To my autoscaling group, I added the property:

```
    TargetGroupARNs:
      - !Ref AlbTargetGroup
```

Then, my target group is the following:

```
  AlbTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
     TargetType: ip 
     VpcId: ###########
     Protocol: HTTP 
     Port: 3000
     HealthCheckPath: /hello
     HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
     HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
     HealthyThresholdCount: 2
     UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
```

Note that I hard-coded by VpcId. I am deploying from the CLI. In the console, the error I am getting in the Stack is:

Provided Target Group 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:...' has invalid target type. Please ensure all provided Target Groups have target type of instance

Comment: The error asks you to have `TargetType: instance` but you have `TargetType: ip`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue. My `TargetType` needs to be set to `ip`, but I get an error saying that it should be type `instance`.

Comment: @mark s. Setting my type to instance worked in my case

Comment: @niketp There are good reason why one often can't do so, for instance ECS tasks with `awsvpc` networking

Answer (score 4):

The link between Application LoadBalancer and AutoScalingGroup needs to be configured differently depending on whether the ALB TargetGroup use TargetType `ip` or `instance`.  With `instance` you use:

```
TargetGroupARNs:
   - !Ref LoadBalancerTargetGroup
```

with `ip` the answer depends on the actual target.  For instance with ECS you typically specify it in the Service definition:

```
LoadBalancers:
  - ContainerName: ContainerName
    ContainerPort: 8080
    TargetGroupArn: !Ref LoadBalancerTargetGroup
```

If you the `instance` type ASG reference to an `ip` ALBTG then you will get the `Please ensure all provided Target Groups have target type of instance` error.

Answer (score 0):

**TERRAFORM CASE**

The answer by [Typhlosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311372/typhlosaurus) pointed me in the right direction. In my case, I was trying to do this same thing through Terraform, and I was getting the error

> Provided Target Group (...) has invalid target type. Please ensure all provided target groups have target type of instance

This is because, as they pointed out, I was using in my Terraform configuration of the AutoScalingGroup, the attribute TargetGroupsArn, instead of the LoadBalancers one.